# Initialize a List<Double[]> with single dimension and 3 elements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have tried many tutorials but none seem to work in this case. I need a `List<Double[3]>` But don't seem to be able to come up with the right syntax. I have tried:

```
List<double[]> points = new List<double> {0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
List<double[3]> points = new List<double> {0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
List<double[]> points = new List<double[]> {};
```

Later on I am doing:

```
pointDouble[0] = Convert.ToDouble(pointString[0]);
pointDouble[1] = Convert.ToDouble(pointString[1]);
pointDouble[2] = Convert.ToDouble(pointString[2]);
points.Add(pointDouble);
```

If I get the initialization to work then I get a mismatch when I try to add the `pointDouble[]` to the list. Usually the message that `double[]` cannot be converted to `Double`.

Comment: Try following :  List<double[]> points = new List<double[]>() { (new List<double>() {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}).ToArray() };

Comment: Did you want a list of doubles, or a list of an array of doubles? If you want a list of array of doubles. then this works: `List<double[]> points = new List<double[]> { new double[] { 0, 0, 0 }, new double[] { 0, 0, 0 }, new double[] { 0, 0, 0 } };`

Comment: It seems that you should be using a class rather than `double[]`, but to answer your question `List<double[]> points = new List<double[]> { new double[] { 0, 0 ,0},  new double[] { 0, 0 ,0}, new double[] { 0, 0 ,0} };` is the right syntax

Comment: Better answer : List<double[]> points = new List<double[]>() { (new double[] {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}) };

Comment: @jdweng - that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a list of triplets of doubles, consider instead creating an object that will hold 3 doubles. This gives your code some semantic meaning, is much easier to read and prevents you mistakenly adding an array of 4 or 5 doubles to your list. For example, if you were trying to store 3D coordinates, you might have this:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

And have a list of this class instead:

```
var coords = new List<Coordinate>();
```

This means you could also have a nice constructor on the class, for example:

```
public Coordinate(double x, double y, double z)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
}
```

And it's nice and easy to add new items to your list:

```
coords.Add(new Coordinate(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: Yes, I like that and would do it on a regular basis in vb.net. What I am doing is reading a file with x/y/z coordinates. They ultimately need to end up in a double[?][3] array. When i do the points.ToArray how would I get the Coordinate class as an array?

Comment: You could do `var result = coords.Select(c => new[] { c.X, c.Y, c.Z }).ToArray();` which will give you ` double[][]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a generic collection argument T for List, since you cannot force the number of items to be consistent/constant is asking for trouble. (double[3] is not a type, double[] is).

If you do not want the overhead of a class to represent your data and you want to ensure the number of items stays the same for each item, you can use the more lightweight "bundle of named stuff" ValueTuple for this purpose:

```
var points = new List<(double x, double y, double z)>() {
               (5.0, 6.0, 7.0)
             };

points.Add((1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
var point = points[0];
var nonsensicalSUm = point.x + point.y + point.z;
```

Comment: Interesting, just learning C#. Will definitely remember tbis trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a syntax issue, this works perfectly :

```
List<double[]> points = new List<double[]> { new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }};
```

In most of your exemples the initializer isn't even the main issue, you can't assign something to something of another type, a list of "double array" is not a list of "double"

```
List<double[]> points = new List<double> /*What happens after this point doesn't matter, you're trying to create a new list of double, and to assign it to a list of arrays, this cannot work*/ {0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
```

The syntax for collection initializers works as expected, just just have collections inside collections, so each "item" in the collection is a collection that also can be initialized, let's cut down the steps for my working example :

```
List<double[]> points = new List<double[]> 
{ 
    // Here we are in the list initializer, we can create elements of the type expected by the list
    //the list expect double ARRAYS, not doubles as you declared a List<double[]> not a List<double>
    new double[]
    {
        // Here we are in the double[] initializer, a double[] is a collection of doubles, so we can initialize it with doubles
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0 
    }
};
```

This works with any amount of nesting as simple or complex as it is, if for example you went with something crazy like a List>>> then you would initialize it as such :

```
var MyList = new List<List<List<List<double[]>>>>
{//Fill the outer list
     new List<List<List<double[]>>>
     {// Fill one level down
         new List<List<double[]>>
         {// etc
             new List<double[]>
             {// and finally fill that bottom most list with a double array
                 new double[]
                 {// With however many elements you want
                    0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

That aside it is very likely you would be better off not working with arrays directly but working with a class or struct to encapsulate your data, for exemple you mention points, if you want a collection of 3D points it would be easier to not represent each point as a double[] but as a class with X Y Z properties :

```
public class Point
{
    public double X {get;set;}
    public double Y {get;set;}
    public double Z {get;set;}
}
```

And then create it by using collection and property initializers as such:

var MyPoints = new List
   {
       new Point
       {// Fill the properties of your point here
           X = 0.0,
           Y = 0.0,
           Z = 0.0
       }
   };

Also note that in your specific case your point is at 0.0, if you intialize it that way you can skip the initalizer alltogether and just do new Point() as floats/doubles will default to 0.0